# How to cast abstract class into type T?

Tags: c#

I have an abstract class:

```
abstract class A {
    // some stuff
    float val = 0;
    abstract float Foo();
}

class B1 : A {
    override float Foo() {
        Console.WriteLine("B1: " + val);
    }
}

class B2 : A {
    override float Foo() {
        Console.WriteLine("B2: " + val);
    }
}
```

and I have a `List<A> a` and I want to get a first item of given type T:

```
public T GetTypeFromList<T>() {
    foreach (var item in a) {
        T tmp = item as T; // doesn't compile
        if (tmp != null)
            return tmp;
    }
    throw new Exception("Type isn't in list.");
}
```

Is there a way to do it?
**Edit:**
It shows: The type parameter 'T' cannot be used with the 'as' operator
          because it does not have a class type constraint nor a 'class'
          constraint

Comment: What is the type `T` supposed to be? You can't convert `A` to just any type

Comment: Normally when things don't compile, the compiler will give you a reason why. Please can you share that reason with us?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For making your code to work you have to add `where` constraint to your method:

`static T GetTypeFromList<T>(List<A> a) where T: class` and then it will work.

Because, as you are using `as` keyword, it converts the object to a given ***reference or nullable value type***. In case of failed conversion the result of `as` operator will be `null`. And `null` is valid only for nullable types. For satisfying the compiler you have to add `class` constraint to your method signature.

***But***, there is already built-in method exits in `System.Linq` namespace for that purpose. It is called [`OfType<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.8). It filters the elements of an `IEnumerable` based on a specified type.

`var b2s = list.OfType<B2>();`

And for getting the first item you can make use of `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` which will return `null` if such element is not exist in the collection:

`var b2 = list.OfType<B2>().FirstOrDefault(); // or First()`

By the way, if you will take a look to the implementation of `OfType<>` you will see that it returns [`OfTypeIterator`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,d25cf953c577dcd6) and inside that method it just iterates over the collection and uses `is` operator to find out the objects with desired type:

```
 static IEnumerable<TResult> OfTypeIterator<TResult>(IEnumerable source) {
            foreach (object obj in source) {
                if (obj is TResult) yield return (TResult)obj;
            }
        }
```

At the end would like to note, using `as` keyword will give better performance in that situation. But in case `OfType<>`, `is` operator  is used at first to check the type and then conversion will happen. So, if performance is important for you, you can continue to use your own implementation.

Comment: But the OP wants only the first item

Comment: Should really use `FirstOrDefault()` or add an exception handler.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `as` for checking the type. Use `is` instead:

```cs
if (item is T)
    return (T)item;
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast) is the detailed explanation about Type casting in msdn.

Comment: Not `(T)item;`?

Answer (score 3):

Well one way is to use LINQ `.First` method. You could heck the type for each element and return the first element that is of type `T`. `.First` throws exception if no element found:

```
List<A> myList;
var obj = (MyTargetType)myList.First(e => e is MyTargetType);
```

As an aside: You can only use operator `as` for [reference and nullable types](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-as-operator-keyword/).